# CSS expanding div with variable height

Tags: css, html

I found this code for collapsible css div here at stackoverflow and I want to use multiple instances of this on one page, but when I click any of the "read more" links it opens the first instance only.

How to modify this script to make each link open only the div associated with it?.

The source: http://jsfiddle.net/QkKej/

```
function growDiv() {
  var growDiv = document.getElementById('grow');
  if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
    growDiv.style.height = 0;
  } else {
    var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
    growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
  }
  document.getElementById("more-button").value=document.getElementById("morebutton").value=='Read more'?'Read less':'Read more';
}
```

The page where i'm using it: http://www.udayansalimbanerjee.com/articles

Comment: Your problem is that ids are supposed to be unique. If you have more than one element labeled id="grow" then any time you do getElementById("grow") it will only get the first instance.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, Accordian/Collapsible is the best option for what you need. Check this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Modify these attributes:

```
id="more-button" ---> class="more-button"
id="grow" ---> class="grow"
```

Additionally complete onclick:

```
onclick="growDiv(this)"
```

Then you can use jQuery (I see, the site supports it):

```
function growDiv(elem) {
    var elEq = $(".more-button").index(elem);
    $(elem).val(
        $(".grow").eq(elEq).is(":visible") ? "Read more" : "Read less"
    );
    $(".grow").eq(elEq).slideToggle("fast");
}
```

This should do the trick. :)

**Edit:** I almost forget the "Read more/less" button.